# jacorb.orb warning em Jboss EAP 7 / Wildfly 10

Tags: java, warnings, corba, wildfly-10, jboss-eap-7

SO... I'm receiving strange WARNs from a application in JBoss-EAP 7 / Wildfly 10:

```
[Server:teste] INFO  2017-02-15 13:52:02,669 [jacorb.orb] Initialising ORB with ID:
[Server:teste] WARN  2017-02-15 13:52:02,701 [jacorb.orb] unable to build ORBInitializer from class true: Ignoring
[Server:teste] INFO  2017-02-15 13:52:02,750 [orb.interceptors] InterceptorManager started with 0 Server Interceptors, 0 Client Interceptors and 1 IOR Interceptors
```

This app have ten years and need the CORBA libs to use a JMS Queue.

Should I worry? 
What this WARNING mean?

[EDITED]

```
Additional logs popout out now:

javax.naming.InvalidNameException: Couldn't resolve initial reference: NameService [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0]
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.Utils.wrapNamingException(Utils.java:52)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.getORBReferenceWithRetry(ORBHelper.java:644)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.getORBReference(ORBHelper.java:594)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.InitialContextFactoryImpl.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactoryImpl.java:85)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.InitialContextFactoryImpl.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactoryImpl.java:31)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:46)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:114)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:99)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:89)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:43)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at com.alu.feeder.tasks.ExpediterRfbNotificationConsumerTask.executarProcesso(ExpediterRfbNotificationConsumerTask.java:88)
        at com.alu.feeder.tasks.ExpediterRfbNotificationConsumerTask.run(ExpediterRfbNotificationConsumerTask.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:260)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0
        at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:1609)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.getORBReferenceWithRetry(ORBHelper.java:631)
        ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, The problem happens because weblogic.jar contains a version of antlr.jar which is loaded by a classloader, while the hibernate stuff are loaded by another classloader. So when the server runs it’s using the version of antlr bundled with weblogic which cannot see the hibernate classes.

I follow this solution and all become OK: https://thejavablog.wordpress.com/tag/antlr/

Answer (score 1):

That's the CORBA subsystem which allows for inter-operation with older CORBA servers. You can ignore this. I'm more familiar with Wildfly 9 so I am not sure you can remove the ORB (Object Request Broker) from Wildfly 10 but it is probably worth looking into if the warning bothers you.

I used CORBA in the 90's. It wasn't a pleasant experience so I doubt you will want to use it.

Comment: This Application have ten year and use CORBA from your on WEB-INF\lib.